# How to inherit function from extend controller in OOP symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I would like to know if this is possible in Object Oriented Programming in php. I have a controller

```
class BaseController extends Controller{

   /**
   * @Route("/sample", name="sample")
   */
   public function postSampleAction(Request $request){

   }
}
```

and I have a file called ProductEvent and PriceEvent

```
class ProductEvent extends BaseController{

   public function checkEvent(){
      echo "product event";
   }
}

class PriceEvent extends BaseController{

       public function checkEvent(){
          echo "price event";
       }
    }
```

as you can see I extend the BaseController. What I want to happen is that I need to put the `checkEvent()` to the BaseController in `postSampleActioin()`

```
class BaseController extends Controller{

       /**
       * @Route("/sample", name="sample")
       */
       public function postSampleAction(Request $request){
         $this->checkEvent();
       }
    }
```

I don't know if this is a proper way. I want to test if that will echo the `checkEvent()` function.

Sorry my mistake. I forgot to add what framework do I used. I used symfony for this.

Comment: Thats not possible. Inheritance just runs in one direction. you would need to implement that function in your Basecontroller and it will be available in your child-classes.

Comment: You'll be better off implementing the `checkEvent()` function in the parent class. Then the child classes can easily override.

Comment: What is your exact requirement? Your approach will not support your requirement.

Comment: all I just want is to echo the function checkEvent() in BaseConroller when route call the postSampleAction(). I already add the checkEvent function in the parent but nothing echo.

Comment: Are you asking if this is possible, or if this a good way of doing it? Because testing [should have given you the result fairly easily](https://repl.it/repls/MustyExtrovertedLocus)...

Comment: @yivi thanks for the link. Yes I'm asking if that is possible but it seems it only work in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

That means you want to make `BaseController` an *incomplete, [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)* class which requires to be inherited and the `checkEvent` method to be implemented there:

```
abstract class BaseController extends Controller {
   public function postSampleAction(Request $request) {
       $this->checkEvent();
   }

   abstract public function checkEvent();
}
```

You now cannot instantiate `BaseController` by itself, and any inheriting non-abstract class needs to implement `checkEvent`; that gives you the required type safety that allows you to depend on `checkEvent` in `postSampleAction`.

Comment: Sorry my big mistake. I thought It is OOP is a problem. I forgot to add what framework I used. This is applicable but the route of symfony not working. Again, sorry. :(